# Flutter NoSuchMethodError in Bloc

Tags: flutter

I am stuck a little bit, I have a Bloc in my flutter app, which needs to be call the configuration check (isConfigured()) when the camera finds the qr code. But I always run into
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error NoSuchMethodError: The method 'isConfigured' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isConfigured() occurred in bloc Instance of 'QrBloc'.

this is the Bloc

```
class QrBloc extends Bloc<QrEvent, QrState> {
  final ValidateTicket validateTicket;
  final ConfigureCode configureCode;
  final QrCodeRepository repository;

  QrBloc(
      {@required ValidateTicket validateTicket,
      @required ConfigureCode configureCode,
      this.repository})
      : assert(validateTicket != null, configureCode != null),
        validateTicket = validateTicket,
        configureCode = configureCode;

  @override
  QrState get initialState => InitialState();

  @override
  Stream<QrState> mapEventToState(
    QrEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is QrCodeScanned) {
      final bool isConfigured = await repository.isConfigured();
      if (isConfigured) {
        final result = await validateTicket(ValidateParams(code: event.qrCode));
        yield* _eitherTicketOrErrorState(result);
      } else {
        yield ConfigurationState();
      }
    } else if (event is SaveConfiguration) {
      final failureOrNot =
          await configureCode(ConfigureParams(code: event.qrCode));
      yield* _eitherConfigOrErrorState(failureOrNot);
    }
  }

  Stream<QrState> _eitherConfigOrErrorState(
    Either<Failure, ConfigurationQrCodeModel> either,
  ) async* {
    yield either.fold(
      (failure) => Error(message: _mapFailureToMessage(failure)),
      (qrCode) => InitialState(),
    );
  }

  Stream<QrState> _eitherTicketOrErrorState(
    Either<Failure, TicketModel> either,
  ) async* {
    yield either.fold(
      (failure) => Error(message: _mapFailureToMessage(failure)),
      (qrCode) {
        if (qrCode.ticketValid == true) {
          return ValidTicketState(ticket: qrCode);
        } else {
          return InvalidTicketState(ticket: qrCode);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  String _mapFailureToMessage(Failure failure) {
    switch (failure.runtimeType) {
      case ServerFailure:
        return serverExceptionText;
      default:
        return unexpectedExceptionText;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the call

sl().add(QrCodeScanned(qrCode: data));

Answer (score 0):

Where is QrBloc initially instantiated? I believe that the repository field is null. Usually, when it says "The method 'xyz' was called on null." It means that that specific method was called from a null value.

Comment: the QRBloc is instantiated